# Use one laravel session for both projects

Tags: laravel, session, authorization

I have sites:

```
example.com
support.example.com
```

I use one db with tables for both sites, to use a common table `users`.

**I need when user authorized on main site, user session will be saved for sudomain.**

I set on main site config param in `config/session.php` to `domain => '.example.com'`. But, after I go to `support.example.com` I don't have user session, and redirect me to `support.example.com/login`.

Also, I'm set `driver => file/cookie/databse` but I got same result.

P.S. Yes, I cleared all session and cache, I used chrome incognito mod for every changes.

Comment: Everything was much easier, it was also necessary to establish the same APP_KEY for both apps